# jQuery Ajax loading external content - show a loading icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got the following code that loads content dynamically into a div:

```
function loadContent(page){
    $("#contentPlaceHolder").load("/ajax/content?page=" + page);
}
```

I use the the following onclick methods to call the content onclick="loadContent('profile')"

It works well, but can anyone tell me how I can display loading.gif while the content is loading?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
function loadContent(page){
    $("#contentPlaceHolder").html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
    $("#contentPlaceHolder").load("/ajax/content?page=" + page);
}
```

Put the gif-file in the div, and when the content loads, the image will be replaced with the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#contentPlaceHolder').html('<img src="loading img url" alt="" style="background-position: center center;" /> ');

function loadContent(page){
    $("#contentPlaceHolder").load("/ajax/content?page=" + page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really basic but something like this should work:

```
var $img $('<img/>', {src: 'loading.gif'});
$('#contentPlaceHolder').empty().append($img);
$("#contentPlaceHolder").load("/ajax/content?page=" + page);
```

It creates an `<img>` element with the correct `src` value (loading.gif), adds that to the content holder, then sends the AJAX call to load the new content. Since that will replace the existing content the loading animation will be removed when it completes.

Answer (score 0):

I have used it whenever i select an option from the Select dropdown. And You don't need to include inside ajax..

```
$("#Select_Dropdown").change(function() {                   
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="imges/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
function loadContent(page){

//Append a loader gif with class for css styling (centered in view):
$("#content-wrap").append('<img class="loader" src="loader.gif" />');

   $("#contentPlaceHolder").load("/ajax/content?page=" + page, function() {
//remove loader, but I'd probably use a css animation or greensock for a nice fade
       $(".loader").remove();
   });
}
```